# Generate a matrix for a puzzle solver prolog program

Tags: matrix, prolog

I have written a prolog program to solve and display the solution for a sudoku like puzzle. At first I used something like this if the grid was e.g. 4x4:

```
main:-
     Matrix = [[_,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_]],
     solve_puzzle(Matrix),
     display_matrix(Matrix).
```

But I'd like to be able to set the size of the matrix so then I wrote this:

```
generate_list(N, [ ]) :-
    N =< 0, !.
generate_list(N, [_ | T]) :-
    N > 0,
    N2 is N - 1,
    generate_list(N2, T).

generate_matrix(_, N, []) :-
    N =< 0, !.
generate_matrix(M, N, [R|T]) :-
    generate_list(M,R),
    N2 is N - 1,
    generate_matrix(M, N2, T).
```

And then I could do:

```
main:-
    Rows = 4, Columns = 4,
    generate_matrix(Columns,Rows,Matrix),
    solve_puzzle(Matrix),
    display_matrix(Matrix).
```

But this seems to slow down my program. Is there a better way to generate an N x M matrix?

Comment: If you want to create a list of a given size, `N`, just use `length(List, N)`.

Comment: It is strange that you should be able to notice (or even measure) a slowdown of your program because of this code. Can you show the timings you got?

Comment: @Boris makes an excellent point. Are you creating a very large number of small matrices, or one or a few very large ones? Or a lot of large ones? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A combination of `length/2` and `maplist/2` works well here:

```
length_list(N, List) :- length(List, N).

generate_matrix(Cols, Rows, Matrix) :-
    length_list(Rows, Matrix),
    maplist(length_list(Cols), Matrix).
```

I defined `length_list/2` to put the length argument first in order to use it in `maplist/2`.

`length/2` is relational, so when you call `length/2` with the length instantiated (say, `N`), but with the list argument as variable, it results in `[_,_, ..., _]` with `N` elements. So the first `length_list` creates a list, `Matrix`, that looks like, `[_, _, _, ..., _]` with length `Rows`. Then the following `maplist/2` will, for each element (row `R`) of `Matrix`, call `length_list(Cols, R)` which yields in place of each `_` a list, `[_, _, ..., _]` of length `Cols`.

`maplist/2` will call the first argument as a predicate on each element of the second argument, a list. Since we're giving it `length_list(Cols)`, it is calling, for each element in `[_, _, ..., _]`, `call(length_list(Cols), _)`, which is equivalent to, `call(length_list(Cols, _))`, which will instantiate `_` with `[_, _, ..., _]`, an anonymous variable list with length `Cols`.

I did some quick timing checks using SWI Prolog's `time/1` and the above approach appears to be significantly faster.